# Closing sockets connection

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I have 2 threads running a chat program such that one is a server and the other is a client, everything works fine till i click the quit button.

since the Socket of the Thread in which the Quit button was clicked get asynchronously closed while the other socket trying to read data, the reading socket in the /living thread gets disturbed by the closure and fires an error mssg, while exepcted to properly close its own socket too and die quietly.

i need suggetions to over come this...

this is the error mssg i get:

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at chatSockets.ChatClient.run(ChatClient.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and that is the code :

```
public void run() {
    try {
        if (type==Type.CLIENT) {
            socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
        } else {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            socket = ss.accept();
        }
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));

        while (!socket.isInputShutdown()) {
            chat.append(in.readLine()+"\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String s = name + " : " + chat.getMssg();
    JButton src=(JButton)e.getSource();
    if (src.getText()=="Quit") {
        out.close();
        try {
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else {
        out.println(s);
        chat.append(s + "\n");
        chat.clearPanel();
    }

}
```

Comment: Now what is your exact problem?

Comment: You must read from a socket to properly detect that it has been closed by the other side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Just handle the closing of the socket on the other end in the catch block and continue execution.

From the javadoc:

> ```
> public String readLine()
>                 throws IOException
>
> Read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a 
> line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed 
> immediately by a linefeed.
>
> Returns:
>     A String containing the contents of the line, not including any 
>     line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been 
>     reached 
> Throws:
>     IOException - If an I/O error occurs
> ```

So you have two options here: either rely on the fact that an `IOException` is thrown when the other end closes the socket and do cleanup in the catch block or if you want a clean way of shutting down send a special "stop token" to the other thread signaling it that you are exiting and that it should close the socket on its end.

Comment: yes, different Solution from different people, and if the problem is solved in this way, why your prof go nuts?

Comment: Yes, that *is* sure. An exception being thrown is just the normal behavior if the other side closes the connection "unexpectedly". There's nothing wrong in using it. - If you can adapt your protocol to send "end of stream" notifications to the other end, that may work, too, of course. - Oh, and besides: How else should *String readline()* signal to the caller that the connection is gone than via exception?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that client is working after the server is up ?

if you try to create a client socket connection before server socket. it will not open the socket.

Comment: yes i am certain, i actually manage to chat between the client and the server chat interface, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch the exception in client side when the server is not up.