# Cannot see data from a simple Java Proxy Server

Tags: java, sockets, curl, networking, proxy

I have implemented a simple **proxy-service** to eavesdrop on messages *to & from* a micro-service (MS). It basically has a **ServerSocket** listening for incoming connections and forwards requests over via a **Socket** connection to the MS.

It also receives the responses from the MS and forwards it to the client.

I am eavesdropping on the messages and printed them out for now. *(I intend to do other validation stuff later)*

However, my problem is that I don't see the data itself that is returned by the **MS** in the response. I only see the HTTP header details.

Example:

***1. from client to proxy***

```
curl http://localhost:9099/anrl/hello/Kandy2
```

***2. message printed by proxy-service upon receiving the above request:***

```
Incoming from Client [95] bytes --------------->
 GET /anrl/hello/Kandy2 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9099
User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
Accept: */*

-----------------------
```

***3. response from MS printed by the proxy-service***

```
Incoming from Server [82] bytes --------------->
 GET /anrl/hello/Kandy2 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9099
User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
Accept: */*

-----------------------
Incoming from Server [14] bytes --------------->
 GET /anrl/hello/Kandy2 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9099
User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
Accept: */*

-----------------------
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
   at shabir.mcgill.proxy.service.ProxyService.runServer(ProxyService.java:124)
   at shabir.mcgill.proxy.service.ProxyService.main(ProxyService.java:32)
```

***4. response printed in the client console***

```
Hello Kandy2.
```

I am expecting to see the response message **('Hello Kandy2.')** in one of the outputs printed in ***(3)*** above. But, I don't see anything there. However, the intended response seems to be reaching my client program *(cURL in the example above)* and is being printed out neatly as shown in **(4)**.

Also, I am thinking as what the *exception* at the end denotes?

It is thrown by this line:

```
while ((bytes_read = from_server.read(replyBuffer)) != -1)
```

But, this doesn't stop from the response being delivered to the client.

Can someone help me understand what's happening here and as to how I can get the **data** extracted from the *stream* received by the proxy-service from both the **client** and the **micro-service**.

**------------------------**
**EDIT**

I don't retrieve any header information from the stream. I just read all the bytes from the Socket stream and print it.

```
final InputStream from_client = client.getInputStream();
final InputStream from_server = server.getInputStream();

while ((bytes_read = from_client.read(requestBuffer)) != -1) {
    to_server.write(requestBuffer, 0, bytes_read);
    System.out.println("Incoming from Client [" + bytes_read + "] bytes --------------->\n " +
    new String(requestBuffer, Charsets.UTF_8) + "-----------------------");
    to_server.flush();
}


while ((bytes_read = from_server.read(replyBuffer)) != -1) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
        System.out.println("Incoming from Server [" + bytes_read + "] bytes --------------->\n " +
        new String(requestBuffer, Charsets.UTF_8) + "-----------------------");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    to_client.write(replyBuffer, 0, bytes_read);
    to_client.flush();
}
```

Thank You
Shabir

Comment: Show us more code. Like how you retrieve the headers...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto - I have included the code portions as to how I read and print the information. **client** and **server** are two **Socket** objects.

Comment: The `new String(buffer, "UTF-8")` call can fail, since your read might have occurred in the middle of a multi byte-encoded unicode character. Well, it would fail silently but it wouldn't necessarily show you what was sent.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Yeah that's where I also think the problem is, in terms of viewing the data. Any **suggestions** or **leads** as to how I could read the contents best to be able to see the data too?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Found the issue. Not what we thought. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer for the issues:

1. Reason I did not see any data in the **sout** was because, in the second loop:

> I read from the **service** into ***reply_buffer***, but am printing ***request_buffer***. So, if you see **(3)** it's the same thing printed over and over again. By printing out the correct ***reply_buffer*** I get the following as intended:

```
-----------------------
Incoming from Server [82] bytes --------------->
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 15
Content-Type: *//*

-----------------------
Incoming from Server [15] bytes --------------->
 Hello Kandy2..

Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 15
Content-Type: */*

-----------------------
```

2. Reason for the **exception** is because there is no way for the program to know that the server end had closed it's connection other than by an exception that is thrown to indicate this when trying to read. This is because the proxy-service has no way of knowing how much more data is left or whether this is the last bit of incoming data.

   As explained [in this stack-overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941413/closing-sockets-connection) the only option is to catch the exception and gracefully pass-by or to assign a **special-token** from the server to indicate that's the last bit of data that is sent.

Thank You All
Shabir